# PXE and GRUB - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: grub2, pxe

I'm working on setting up netboot, and got it working with one motherboard, but it doesn't quite seem to work with another; and I don't see enough output to figure out why.

So, the setup on the 'PXE server' is that DHCP and TFTP reside on the same server, and DHCP is configured with:

```
root@vogon:/etc/dhcp# cat dhcpd.conf
option domain-name "somewhere.com";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.50.9, 8.8.8.8;
allow booting;
allow bootp;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.50.10 192.168.50.190;
  option routers 192.168.50.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.50.255;
  next-server 192.168.50.9;
  #filename "debian-installer/amd64/bootnetx64.efi";
  filename "grubx64.efi";
}
```

TFTP uses `/srv/tftp` as root dir, and `grubx64.efi` will read `/debian-installer/amd64/grub/grub.cfg` because I'm using the bootloader from the debian 11 distro:

```
root@vogon:/srv/tftp# cat debian-installer/amd64/grub/grub.cfg
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
set gfxpayload=text
set timeout=-1

menuentry 'Debian 11'{
    set background_color=black
    linux    /debian/11/amd64/linux priority=low vga=788 ---
    initrd   /debian/11/amd64/initrd.gz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 20.04" {
        linux /ubuntu/20.04/amd64/linux only-ubiquity ip=dhcp ---
        initrd /ubuntu/20.04/amd64/initrd.gz
}
```

I have used this setup to successfully install both Debian 11 and Ubuntu 20.04 on a ROG Strix X570-F Gaming motherboard with an AMD Ryzen 9 5950X CPU. In `/var/log/syslog` I see the following from the tftp server:

```
Jul  8 13:33:33 vogon in.tftpd[45602]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename grubx64.efi
Jul  8 13:33:33 vogon in.tftpd[45602]: tftp: client does not accept options
Jul  8 13:33:33 vogon in.tftpd[45603]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename grubx64.efi
Jul  8 13:33:34 vogon in.tftpd[45604]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst
Jul  8 13:33:34 vogon in.tftpd[45605]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst
Jul  8 13:33:34 vogon in.tftpd[45606]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst
Jul  8 13:33:34 vogon in.tftpd[45607]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst
Jul  8 13:33:34 vogon in.tftpd[45608]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /debian-installer/amd64/grub/grub.cfg
Jul  8 13:33:37 vogon in.tftpd[45609]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /ubuntu/20.04/amd64/linux
Jul  8 13:33:40 vogon in.tftpd[45610]: RRQ from 192.168.50.161 filename /ubuntu/20.04/amd64/initrd.gz
```

However, with another motherboard, ASUS ProArt Z690-CREATOR WIFI Intel Z690 PCIe 5.0 ATX, and Intel Core i9 12900KS Special Edition 16 Core Alder Lake Unlocked CPU, I only see the following in the log:

```
Jul 12 10:49:00 vogon in.tftpd[58652]: RRQ from 192.168.50.136 filename grubx64.efi
Jul 12 10:49:00 vogon in.tftpd[58652]: tftp: client does not accept options
Jul 12 10:49:00 vogon in.tftpd[58653]: RRQ from 192.168.50.136 filename grubx64.efi
```

and the text 'Welcome to GRUB!' on the client screen. This text is only found in the bootloader, `grubx64.efi`, so it seems it actually starts running, but never goes on to looking for the other files.

Any suggestions for what I can do to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have the `option boot-size` line anywhere in your dhcpd configuration. Some UEFI implementations require that this option is used to indicate the size of the UEFI PXE bootloader file, so the UEFI firmware will be able to allocate the right amount of memory for it in advance.

Adding the option (with the correct size specified) should never hurt and might help some UEFI implementations. So please run `du -B 512 /srv/tftp/grubx64.efi` to determine the size of the `grub64.efi` file in 512-byte blocks, and then add

```
option boot-size <size in blocks>;
```

within the `subnet` declaration in your `dhcpd.conf` file.

Having the `boot-size` option defined was apparently a requirement for PXE boot with earlier versions of the UEFI specification, but I would not be surprised if later versions have made that optional, or if some firmware authors have just chosen to write a PXE boot file download routine that uses the TFTP `tsize` option to request the TFTP server to tell the total size of the incoming file transfer before it begins, if that option is available.

If adding the `option boot-size` line doesn't help, and the firmware doesn't provide you any useful diagnostics, then you might want to dump the TFTP traffic and analyze it (e.g. with `wireshark`) to verify that the entire file gets transferred. On the PXE boot server, you might do something like this:

```
tcpdump -i eno1 -Knpvv -s0 -w pxe-tftp.cap udp
```

then make a PXE boot attempt while the tcpdump is running, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the tcpdump. You might not be able to filter just the TFTP packets at tcpdump, because the TFTP server may allocate a different port for sending data to the client, and you won't be able to know in advance which port that will be.

Once you get the dump opened in Wireshark, just type in `tftp` into the filter expression bar and you'll see only the TFTP packets you're interested in. Then right-click on any TFTP packet displayed in the packet list window, and make sure `Protocol Preferences` -> `Trivial File Transfer Protocol` -> `Reassemble fragmented TFTP files` is checked. Now you can find the last packet of each TFTP file transfer (should be helpfully marked with `(last)`), open the `Trivial File Transfer Protocol` branch in the packet analysis window, and see a line like:

```
[nn TFTP Fragments (nnnnn bytes): ...]
```

The `(nnnnn bytes)` part will tell you the total transferred size for the file. If it does not match the actual size of the transferred file, you've probably found the cause. Fixing it might require a firmware update, though.

Comment: This is a really good answer - I'm going to try your advice as soon as I get the chance. Thx!

Comment: Here's an odd observation, but maybe it is just because I don't know enough - the last packet captured claims to have a length of 1434 bytes, but the size of data inside is: `Data (1426816 bytes)`, which matches the size of the file on disk.

Comment: Wireshark is reassembling all the packets in the datastream for you, and indicating the total size of the file transferred over multiple packets. If all the TFTP packets are getting acknowledged by the client, it looks like the `grubx64.efi` file is getting transferred correctly and the problem would not seem to be the bootloader file getting truncated in transit. But it might still be a case of insufficient buffer being allocated for the transfer in the client; did you add the `option boot-size 2786;` line to the DHCP configuration?

Comment: I did; that was the first thing I did. Should I make it bigger?

Comment: No, it should accurately describe the size of your bootloader file in 512-byte blocks.

Comment: The problem with the  ASUS ProArt Z690-CREATOR WIFI motherboard sounds like it might be some bug or a compatibility issue. You might want to try another UEFI PXE bootloader instead of GRUB, like [iPXE](https://ipxe.org) for example. I've had good experience with it.

Comment: Interesting. I upgraded the UEFI to the newest, which hasn't solved the problem, but now, after showing only 'Welcome to GRUB!' for a while, it seems to give up and shows 'GRUB version 2.04-20' and an grub command line, which responds to input, but doesn't do anything.